# When did they start counting the days from 1 to 31 in Europe?

Tags: ancient-history, calendar

In history the Romans didn't count their days of a month not by adding each day extra. But instead of that they used three moments in a month, Kalendae, nonae and Idus. And from those days they counted back. 
Now in the 4th century Constantine introduced with his new christian religion also a new kind of dating. The 8 days week was changed in a 7 days week. And also the names of the days changed from A t/m H to the planetairy names of the day, like the roman languages has at the moment.

But was that also the day that they start counting like 1,2,3...28,29,30 of the month?

Comment: Related: [When was the change from kalends, ides...](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/27924/when-was-the-change-from-kalends-ides-and-nones-to-numbers)

Comment: Ok, and that question was asked only 3 weeks ago , what a coincedance! But it looks very duplicate, so if nobody has more to say about it, I will close it.